# Displaying a clip in a transparent rectangle

Tags: video, video-editor, davinci-resolve

So I have Downloaded the dynamic, zoom out-in youtube subscribe thingy and now Im just wondering how can I set my clip into the transparent rectangle, which is changing it's with and height in time (with some ease timing)

Is there a way in Davinci resolve to merge a clip into a transparent rectangle with automatic 'scaling'?

[image]

Comment: You want the final output to contain transparency?  Because that’s possible as long as you use a codec which supports it, but it’s not very entertaining.  It does make sense if you’re building a graphic for future re-use, which is why I’m asking for clarification.

Comment: In the final output, I want to 'insert' my video into the transparent part which you see in the screenshot.
The tricky part is that the transparent part is changing its measurements (width/height), so I can't just crop/reside my video into that, as it will not follow the dynamic width/height change.
So I was wondering whether there is an option to just 'put' my video into that transparent rectangle so that it will automatically adjust itself it its measurements

Comment: so you want to track the corners to correct translations (scale, rotation, location, perspective) but you just want to use scale and location?

Comment: @desperrrr yes, thats the goal

Comment: @Jakub have you tried using the planar tracker node in the fusion tab? there are plenty of good tutorials out there on how to use it (cant give any links at the moment)